# .Net WebAPI not responding when returning HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a problem with web api with action when returning `HttpResponseMessage`. This object I return a stream of audio, this file have about 60kb and in the first time I have success when I call the web api, however, in the next time the web api not responds and the browser stay only loading.

Below following the code:

Why this web api not works/responds in the next time that I call?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/card/playAudio/{text}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PlayAudio(string text)
{
    var audioStream = await _cardService.GetStream(text);
    return CreateAudioResponse(audioStream);
}

private HttpResponseMessage CreateAudioResponse(System.IO.Stream audioStream)
{
    var result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    //HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(audioStream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.mp3", new Guid().ToString());
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = audioStream.Length;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? In the debugger, what line of code is it stuck on? If you use a tool such as Fiddler, what do you see happening? Are you sure GetStream is giving you back a valid stream? Etc. "It doesn't work" type questions are generally difficult to help with.

Comment: I'm debuging and the .net not arrives in the action PlayAudio. Because this that I think that I'm with problem with the HttpResponseMessage with files .mp3, because if I return a HttpResponseMessage empty not have problem.

Comment: having the same issue, any solution?